# How to give sample video stream as input instead of video stream in case of sample audio video demo in case of easyrtc application?

Tags: video, open-source, webrtc, easyrtc

I am developing one application using EasyRtc. In case of simple audio video demo i want to play recorded video as a input instead of the camera stream.How should a i proceed ???
In short as a camera video stream i want to play sample recorded video stream

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Firefox, you can use:

```
stream = video_element.mozCaptureStreamUntilEnded();
```

This has been proposed and there's general agreement to add this to the specs, and has been in Firefox for some time.  Also, canvas.captureStream(); this *just* landed in Firefox Nightly.

See [Bug 1032848](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1032848)